# NestJS GraphQL - I need to create a string array Field

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I have this field in a model but doesn't work

```
@Field(type => [],{ nullable: true })
product: string[];
```

I don't know what I miss.

Comment: Please create a small portion of the env on any only code editor to show what you are trying to achieve. Right now your question is missing adequate information.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the GraphQL type `String`. Therefore change `[]` to `[String]`, an array of strings. You might also want to set `product` optional (with `?`) since it is `nullable`.

```
@Field(type => [String], { nullable: true })
product?: string[];
```